# why 'in' operator with tuple as a key in python so slow?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dict such as:

```
d=dict()
d[('1','2')] = 'value'
```

Then I query the key :

```
if (k1,k2) in d.keys():
```

When there is million records,the speed is a suffering, any problem with the 'in' operator?

Is it sequential search?

I have to  concat str as key to bypass this issue.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Quite interesting problem, I ll look into this

Comment: Your edit introduces an entirely new question: why don't you ask it in a separate question?  I think that would make more sense.

Comment: I rolled the question back to its original form. If you want to ask a different question, ask it in a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newcomer in stackoverflow. Last edit is show the code .

Comment: @lbaby The thing is your edit (that I rolled back) did not actually have `in d.keys()` anywhere. You might wish to take a read of the [faq] and look at how to accept answers.

Answer (score 13):

You should use

```
(k1,k2) in d
```

instead of calling `d.keys()`.

Doing it your way, in Python 2 will result in a linear search and rather negates the benefits of a `dict`. In Python 3 your code is efficient (see comments below) but my version is clearer.

Comment: Does this hold true for both Python 2 and 3? I thought `.keys()` would provide a view object in Python 3, not a list?

Comment: I'm struggling to see why someone would even use ``d.keys()``. In Python 2.x, this will create a list of a million records every time. Even in 3.x, it's still totally redundant.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Even if it creates an iterable view object, the `in` operator will have to perform linear search. You need to apply the `in` operator to the `dict` object.

Comment: And it doesn't do a linear search with `key in d`?  How does it find the matching key, then? Also, wouldn't this happen independently of whether a tuple or a string is used as the key?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A dict view of keys is set-like, so it would have the same performance as the dict itself.

Comment: @Lattyware ah. I thought it was of iterable nature. So in other words there is a big difference between py2 and py3?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Take a read](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dictionary-view-objects) - they are actually very flexible things in Python 3.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks for educating me. I think my answer is accurate now.

Comment: *And it doesn't do a linear search with key in d? How does it find the matching key, then?* -- dict is a hash map, so it creates hash of the key and checks is there is anything there. O(1) operation.

Answer (score 5):

Given Nolen Royalty's addition, I thought I'd make note that you can actually do the `timeit` tests in a slightly better way. By moving the construction of the `dict` into a setup function, we can time only the operations on the `dict`, giving us a result we can compare with easily.

In 3.2:

```
python -m timeit -s 'd = {(str(i), str(j)):"a" for i in range(100) for j in range(1000)}' '_ = ("1", "2") in d.keys()' '_ = (1, 2) in d.keys()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.404 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'd = {(str(i), str(j)):"a" for i in range(100) for j in range(1000)}' '_ = ("1", "2") in d' '_ = (1, 2) in d'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.247 usec per loop
```

You can see the difference. In 3.x, working directly on the `dict` gives us an almost 2x speed increase, which isn't bad.

In 2.7.3:

```
python2 -m timeit -s 'd = {(str(i), str(j)):"a" for i in range(100) for j in range(1000)}' '_ = ("1", "2") in d.keys(); _ = (1, 2) in d.keys()'
10 loops, best of 3: 36.3 msec per loop

python2 -m timeit -s 'd = {(str(i), str(j)):"a" for i in range(100) for j in range(1000)}' '_ = ("1", "2") in d' '_ = (1, 2) in d'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.197 usec per loop
```

In 2.x, the difference is truly *staggering*. Using `dict.keys()` takes 36,300 microseconds, while just the `dict` takes under 0.2 microseconds. That's nearing **two hundred thousand** times faster.

Just thought that was worth a note.

Edit:

Tim made an interesting comment, so I decided to do anther test. I tried just constructing the list, and then just doing the hash lookup, results as follows:

```
python2 -m timeit -s 'd = {(str(i), str(j)):"a" for i in range(100) for j in range(1000)}' 'd.keys()' 'd.keys()'
100 loops, best of 3: 5.84 msec per loop

python2 -m timeit -s 'd = {(str(i), str(j)):"a" for i in range(100) for j in range(1000)}' -s 'l=d.keys()' '_ = ("1", "2") in l' '_ = ("1", "2") in l'
10 loops, best of 3: 25.3 msec per loop
```

You can see that on a large dict like this, constructing the list takes about 1/6th of the time, doing the search through the list 5/6ths of the time.

Comment: Great - and I'm pretty sure that this vast difference is *not* primarily because of linear search vs. hash lookup but because of the construction of a list of keys for every iteration, as you suggested in your comment to @DavidHeffernan's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I had no idea you could easily pass a setup function like that.  +1

Comment: @NolenRoyalty It's really useful - you can also do multiple setups by using the flag multiple times. You can also avoid using semicolons by putting more quoted strings. Makes doing complex tests much easier.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Actually, I just did a check and edited my answer to add in my results - most of the time is spent on the search. I must admit, I thought that the list creation would be the biggest factor. (Then again, I didn't think the difference would be *this* massive either).

Comment: @Lattyware: Wow. Great, thanks for getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: @TimPietzcker No worries, it was interesting. Yet another reason to love Python 3, these kind of mistakes are much harder to make.